# How can i write to the windows event log using C# (I'm getting some kind of error)?

Tags: c#, event-log

I have written:

```
.
.
.
//Log exception to the event log
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("PodaHIS")) {
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("PodaHIS", "Application");   
}

EventLog eventLog = new EventLog();
eventLog.Log = "Application";
eventLog.Source = "PodaHIS";
eventLog.WriteEntry(error.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

I have also enabled read permission to LOCALMACHINE\ASPNET.

And in return i get:

```
The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccesible logs: Security.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog

What is need to do was grant the "**Security**" sub key of the EventLog Key read permission. After that i restarted my IIS.

Answer (score 1):

this kb artical explains the steps required to give your asp process the correct security rights to write to the event log...

[kb](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;329291)

Comment: My problem had to do with the Security sub key and the restarting of IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permission on the box that you want to write the event log to, then you can run [a script that I wrote](http://spcrew.com/blogs/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=19).

Comment: Maybe you could paste your code in since it's not too big. If the link break someday, your answer will still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a higher level of access is required to create a source in the event log. It's possible that the reference to Security log is coincidental and it is just reporting that as a possible cause. If you go in as an administrator and create the PodaHIS source yourself, you might then find that it can write to it.

Answer (score 0):

What it your deployment environment? If it is Vista/Server 2008 then adding worker account into Administrators group won't work due to UAC.

This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/00a043ae-9ea1-4a55-8b7c-d088a4b08f09/) explains the problem in details.
But I would recommend try creating an event source manually so ASPNET won't need to create it...

Comment: I've found a solution if my answer below.