# How to write to the windows syslog using Python 2.7 when NTEventLogHandler throws an exception

Tags: python, windows, logging

I'm trying to write data to the system log on Windows 7 using Pythons (2.7) `logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler`. This does not work as there is apparently some registry access being denied. The software will be run without any special access rights. Is there any way to make this work?

Here is the exception I get:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> from logging import handlers
>>> syslog = handlers.NTEventLogHandler("Something")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 917, in __init__
    self._welu.AddSourceToRegistry(appname, dllname, logtype)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32evtlogutil.py", line 35, in
 AddSourceToRegistry
    "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\EventLog\\%s\\%s" % (eventLogType, app
Name))
pywintypes.error: (5, 'RegCreateKey', 'Access is denied.')
```

Comment: Related: [How can i write to the windows event log using C# (I'm getting some kind of error)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1906077/95735)

Answer (score 0):

"Win32 Extensions for Python" is required to use sysLog on Windows. Are you sure that you have installed it? [1]

From the docs [2]:
The NTEventLogHandler class, located in the logging.handlers module, supports sending logging messages to a local Windows NT, Windows 2000 or Windows XP event log. Before you can use it, you need Mark Hammond’s Win32 extensions for Python installed.

[1] http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

[2] http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html

Comment: As you can see I've got an access denied of the type pywintypes.error which is part of the Win32 extension. So to answer your question: Yes, we can be definitely certain that the Win32 Extensions were installed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was to adjust the permissions in regedit for my account.  In my case, logging to the Application Event Log, I had to add the Full Control permission to

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application**

Setting just the Read permission did not work as this was already in place with the Authorized Users ACE.  Also, the permission has to remain set for each execution (it isn't just a one time setting).

Alternately, you will avoid this error if you can just run your code as Administrator since the Administrators group already has Full Control over these keys.